# Toggle Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground

Tags: c++, qt, setattribute

I've been searching around but haven't found an answer that helps me.
As the Title says i want to toggle the attribute "Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground" on/off.

I need WA_TranslucentBackground but some users of my app reported that this doesn't work in OBS(Open Broadcaster Software) so i have to make a seperate version without the TranslucentBackground.

My Code:

```
void MainWindow::action_widgetMode(){
   if(displayOBS ==0){
       this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground,true);
   }else{
       this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground,false);
   }
   this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint);

   this->activateWindow();
   this->setFocus();
   this->show();
}
```

I am calling this function once upon start. And additionally on a checkbox click where i want to toggle it on/off. This code does work when i restart my application, but i want it to be immediate after the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

Comment: try to call update() or repainr() for main window after you set this attribute

Comment: tried both already but without success

Comment: have your tried `close()` and `show()`? this will make the window disappear and recreates it.

Comment: Hey Felix! Thanks for your reply. I have tried it without success :(